# Is is standard practice to have the same include derivate in a header and source file?

Tags: c++, header-files

When working with say, the standard strings class in c++.
Do you need to have `#include<string>` on both the header and source file?

can you not just have `#include<string>` only on the header file?

Comment: Yes, some people just do it for complete-ness.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Including on the header file may indicate a dependency at the class definition level (for example you are accepting or returning Strings). In this case you have to put the include in the header; however if you are only using Strings in your implementation you may need to include only on the source file.

Answer (score 3):

The best practice is to include an header file individually in every header or source file which requires it.

Including required headers indirectly through other header files gives you the drawback that
when you pull out a included header from source file at some point in future you might end up with obscure compilation errors because of the missing (*indirectly included*)header.

Answer (score 1):

The file inclusion is done by replacing the include directive with the contents of the included header file (in practice, it is probably not done by replacement in a text stream but by a semantically-equivalent operation).

This means that all files included in a header, will be included in files including that header, so no, you don't need to include it twice.

That said, there are many policies for including files and choosing one is more of a matter of what you're focusing on and best practices than what you *need* to do.

For example, you could strive for completeness and include files whenever you use symbols defined in those files.

I've also worked with a project (low level, cross-platform C library) where client code was responsible for including header file dependencies explicitly, before including a header file. This was done to keep the header dependencies explicit, and to eliminate/minimize (as much as possible) hidden dependencies limitations imposed by the library to clients.

In the end, it's up to you (and/or your team).